# react-router: How to set default child route and modify URL accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v3. A piece of my routing code:

```
...
<Route path='dashboard' component={Dashboard}>
  <Route path='overview' component={Overview}/>
  <Route path='scan' component={Scan}/>
</Route>
...
```

I want anyone accessing '/dashboard' to be redirected to '/dashboard/overview'. I know I can use IndexRoute to achieve this but the browser URL does not show the 'overview bit'. Also I will be using 'Link' to route to the 'overview' and 'scan' sections. I need to use its 'activeClassName' feature to apply some styling. Don't think IndexRoute will trigger that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index redirects: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md#index-redirects

```html
<Route path='dashboard' component={Dashboard}>
  <IndexRedirect to="/overview" />
  <Route path='overview' component={Overview}/>
  <Route path='scan' component={Scan}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu please consider to accept the answer if it solved your question